# Webpack Babel 6

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

When I try to compile my javascript with webpack & babel-loader, I get:
(Babel version 6+)

```
Hash: f6a14faa8862d530512e
Version: webpack 1.12.3
Time: 96ms
     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
backend.js  1.75 kB       0  [emitted]  main
backend.js.map  1.43 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} backend.js, backend.js.map (main) 28 bytes [rendered]
[0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]

ERROR in The node API for `babel` has been moved to `babel-core`.
@ multi main
Patched!
```

How do I move the node API for `babel`to `babel-core`?

Comment: npm install babel-core?

Comment: already installed it, found the solution. Had to uninstall babel. See answer

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
npm uninstall babel --save-dev
```

This fixed it. Babel package is deprecated...

Comment: And then `npm install babel-loader babel-core --save-dev`

Comment: Tired of these issues, one fixed one appears (((. Can't start do something but fuNking with this tool wet wet wet tool. Want jQuery and ie6 back this time)

Answer (score 12):

```
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `loader: "babel",` => `loader: "babel-loader",` in webpack config

Hope this help! it's work for me

Answer (score 1):

I did both these commands, then it started working !!

```
npm uninstall babel --save-dev
npm install babel-loader --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be used like this:

```
var babel = require('babel-core');
babel.transform(code, babelOptions);
```